# React bootstrap isn't work when i refreshed page

Tags: reactjs

my route is designed like this:
APP.js

```
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/"  component={Home}/>
        <Route  path="/:category/:postId" component={Posts}/>
        <Route  path="/:category" component={Categories}/>)}/>
    </Switch>
```

index.js:

```
<BrowserRouter >
  <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink- 
to-fit=no">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>React App</title>
 </head>
<body>
<noscript>
  You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

when i through "/" to"/react/8xf0y6ziyjabvozdd253nd",it worked.but after refresh page react-bootstrap isn't work.i want to known why . my code was pushed https://github.com/tulipjie/redux-readable

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: Yes,it doesn't work when i refresh page.since i change my code as Neeraj said ,it work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the Stylesheet `<link>` from index.html and place it in index.js

**index.js**

```
import 'bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';

// ... rest of your code here
```

Assuming you have installed the above packages from npm and are in /node_modules.