# On Page Refresh I get this: “/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am testing my MERN stack app and when I Refresh the browser on a couple of components I get these errors:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/mdb.min.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/styles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/jquery.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/popper.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/jquery.min.js”. 5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308:31:1
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/mdb.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
5e85ba9010ae8d2e58bed308
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/popper.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

When the component loads the first time, it loads fine with all the design and formatting intact. When I press the refresh button all the styling goes away and it becomes plain text.

I am using Redux and React.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React bootstrap isn't work when i refreshed page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332252/react-bootstrap-isnt-work-when-i-refreshed-page)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the files exists in the below folders, chances are they are missing

http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/css/

http://localhost:3000/profile/assets/js/

Also most probably you want the CDN urls for jquery.min, for example,
`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.slim.min.js`

Comment: No actually i have imported them in the index.html in the public folder. Its working fine for other components, when i refresh the styling stays intact. Not for this one though.